# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath':Could not resolve com.android.databinding:library:3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

i am facing a problem with android studio 3.2.1 and the Gradle build version is 4.6. Recently i updated my android studio to 3.2.1 and and gradle is also updated to 4.6. If we remove the dataBinding, erors will be disappears. after adding the dataBinding its giving problem  like

```
  Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could 
  not resolve com.android.databinding:library:3.2.1.

  Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could 
  not resolve com.android.databinding:adapters:3.2.1.

  Unable to resolve dependency for 
  ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve 
   com.android.databinding:library:3.2.1.

  my Gradle build of the project level is
      buildscript {

    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
       maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
 belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
    }

  allprojects {
     repositories {
       google()
        jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
        }
     }
 }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
     }
```

is any one solved this issues please help in this case.I have tried all the trials but did not worked.

```
   my app level gradle is 

   android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sample.mvvmandroidstudio"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
   }


  }

   dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
   layout:1.1.3'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
      androidTestImplementation 
 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
  core:3.0.2'
  }
```

Comment: What is your approach to add data binding? Can you post the `app.gradle` which makes issue.

Comment: ok please check my question its updated with the app.Gradle

Comment: can you check it now i am just updated

Comment: Make sure your offline mode is disabled. and system is connected to active internet.

Comment: You don't have `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` on top of gradle?

Comment: ya i have it. by mistake i did not added in above line of code

Comment: i done the offline disable also its nothing works

Comment: Check answer configuration. and sync.

Comment: In my experience the databinding issues are almost always related to the generated code and the xml usage of that generated code. To narrow it down run assembleRelease --debug from a terminal and get the error to share so we can see exactly what error you are getting. If you simply get the DataBinding not found error on every class that has databinding, it could mean several things. I'll itemize for you once I see you error.

Answer (score 0):

I made some edit in your gradle.

**Project level**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.mvvmandroidstudio"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

Changes I made:

- Removed duplicate google repo
- Removed testing dependencies, as I don't think you use it.

Comment: same error. i will try with again updating the the SDK platform tools let me check

Comment: Did you try deleting .idea, .gradle. and build folder?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by updating my android studio to recent version.

Thanks to Khemraj for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by uncheck the offline work in settings->Build,Execution Deployment->gradle.Hope it will help for you.